# How to get list to whom feed is post through facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Through facebook, I post message on wall using feed dialog box. I want to get list of friends to whom feed is send.

When user select option to share message on specific group of friends, then privacy has value of enum{`EVERYONE`, `ALL_FRIENDS`, `FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS`, `CUSTOM`, `SELF`}.

My question is how to find facebook user id of above list.

Please help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Thu shalt not code for the dark and evil facebook.

Comment: How are you sending the feed to user friends using feed dialog?

Comment: Yes, using feed dialog box.

Comment: Well you can't, its the part of the user's privacy.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"%@",[app.Arr_Facebook_Frnd objectAtIndex:indexpath]);

NSString *userid = [[app.Arr_Facebook_Frnd objectAtIndex:indexpath] objectForKey:@"id"];
NSString *str_name = [[app.Arr_Facebook_Frnd objectAtIndex:indexpath] objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *str_link = @"www.google.com";

NSDictionary *params = @{
                         @"name" : str_name,
                         @"caption" : @"",
                         @"description" : @"",
                         @"picture" : @"",
                         @"link" : str_link,
                         @"to":userid,
                         };

/


// Invoke the dialog
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                       parameters:params
                                          handler:
 ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
         [self.indicator stopAnimating];
     } else {
         if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
             NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
             [self.indicator stopAnimating];
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Story published.");
             [self.indicator stopAnimating];
         }
     }}];
```